# Android ENCODING_PCM_FLOAT Audiotrack issue

Tags: java, android, encoding, floating-point-precision

I'm writing an app to create a sound with depth to 32-bit audio, but can not understand much. I have a code that generates the tone and another that generates the audiotrack. I'm new in this topic, and I have not found what I ask from anywhere, so I open this question.

This generates a 16 bit tone with a sinusoidal equation:

```
void genTone(int numSamples,double sample[],int sampleRate,double freqOfTone,byte generatedSnd[]){
    double x = 0
            for (int i = 0; i < numSamples; ++i) {
                x = i / (sampleRate / freqOfTone);
                sample[i] = Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * x);
            }

    //scaling to the maximum amplitude
    int idx = 0;
    long val = 0;
    for (final double dVal : sample) {

        val = (long) ((dVal * 32767));
            generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) (val & 0x00ff);
            generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) ((val & 0xff00) >>> 8);
    }

}
```

And this is the function that generates the audio track at 16bit:

```
void playSound(int sampleRate, byte generatedSnd[]){
   final AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                    sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, generatedSnd.length,
                    AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);
            audioTrack.write(generatedSnd, 0, generatedSnd.length);
            audioTrack.play();
```

Logically, I rewrote the code in this manner, but the sound output is rather strange. What's wrong?

Part of *genTone* function:

```
//changed byte generatedSnd to float generatedSnd32

void genTone(int numSamples,double sample[],int sampleRate,double freqOfTone,float generatedSnd32[]){
int idx = 0;
long val = 0;
    for (final double dVal : sample) {

        val = (long) ((dVal * 2147483647));
        generatedSnd32[idx++] = (byte) (val & 0x00ff);
        generatedSnd32[idx++] = (byte) ((val & 0xff00) >>> 8);
    }
}
```

And this is the part of the function PlaySound at 32 bit:

```
void playSound(int sampleRate,float generatedSnd32[]){
final AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                    sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_FLOAT, generatedSnd.length,
                    AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);
            audioTrack.write(generatedSnd32, 0, generatedSnd.length,AudioTrack.WRITE_BLOCKING);
            audioTrack.play();
}
```

Comment: Do you know what `generatedSnd32[idx++] = (byte) ((val & 0xff00) >>> 8);` (and all the lines like that) do? Also do you know what ENCODING_PCM_FLOAT is?

Comment: @immibis not exactly, I'm a noob, please tell me.